How to resolve "Source not found" Error in Package Mapping Context in .NET
This is the error I'm facing while intalling any kind of package from the Dotner CLI. Is there any way to resolve this. All solution are appreaciated!!
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
Unhandled exception: Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageInstallerException: Package Source Mapping is enabled, but no source found under the specified package ID: dotnet-ef. See the documentation for Package Source Mapping at https://aka.ms/nuget-package-source-mapping for more details.
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.LoadNuGetSources(PackageId packageId, PackageSourceLocation packageSourceLocation, PackageSourceMapping packageSourceMapping)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.GetBestPackageVersionAsync(PackageId packageId, VersionRange versionRange, PackageSourceLocation packageSourceLocation)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.ToolPackage.ToolPackageDownloader.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<InstallPackage>b__0()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.TransactionalAction.Run[T](Func`1 action, Action commit, Action rollback)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Install.ToolInstallGlobalOrToolPathCommand.Execute()
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.Invoke(ParseResult parseResult)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)

I tried :
dotnet nuget locals all --clear

dotnet nuget add source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --name nuget.org

But none of this seems to work.

Hi @Trushaba B. Jadeja, Please check the %appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config if it contains correct package source.

Firstly please check the %appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config(e.g C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config) if it contains correct package source:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>

Or run command to check current entries:
dotnet nuget list source

Run the command below to clear the cache, then restart the project
dotnet nuget locals -c all

If still not working, a workaround is to use the --add-source parameter directly when installing to specify nuget.org as the source:
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --add-source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json


Checked NuGet.Config has the correct package source, still the same issue.

Hi @TrushabaB.Jadeja, have you tried the workaround I shared? Run: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --add-source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json, also not working?

There can be multiple NuGet.Config files at different levels. To check which one is being used by the dotnet CLI, please run dotnet nuget list source to check if it contains the correct source.

No, dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --add-source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json not working, my version being restricted to .NET Core 3.x.x can be one of reasons, got any suggestion for that?

Hi @TrushabaB.Jadeja, no matter which version of .net core, the dotnet ef tool always can be installed. firstly, what's the error message after you running dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --add-source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json? Still the same error message? then, could you pls tell me the result of running dotnet nuget list source. At last, Have you tried to clean and rebuild the project and then restart the visual studio/vs code to run the command again?

Hi, thanks for the help. The error is now resolved.
The error message said "Package in is not compatible with the current version" and listed some other packages. I installed the packages listed in error message with the mentioned version and then installed the package I was initially planning to install and the problem was solved, thank you for you efforts and help, much appreciated.

You can try this:
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json


This shows:
Unrecognized command or argument '--source'. Unrecognized command or argument 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.

The.NET Core SDK version is lower than 3.0, update the version first
